# Automating the measurement of two profiles of a colour merged image in FIJI (ImageJ)

Tags: java, image-processing, macros, profile, imagej

I've been attempting to write a macro that measures and saves (as a .csv) the pixel intensity profile along a linear ROI of two images merged in the red and green colour channels. The output file would ideally be a single .csv with the x-axis values in one column and the two y-axis values in two additional columns.

The image in question is a stack and the ROI will be user defined every time which both seem to compound issues.

I started by using the BAR "Multichannel Plot Profile" plugin which gives me exactly what I need (plot and .csv format) but I'm struggling when it comes to automating the saving of the data in raw form since you can't macro record clicking the "Data" > "Save Data..." buttons on the plot screen.

I'm aware there are solutions using getProfile() but this only samples the first colour channel. I'm unsure how to modify this to measure two y-axis values in separate channels.

I've tried automatic channel splitter and measuring both channels individually but there are issues with the ROI when the composite is split. Plus this is an image stack which channel splitter doesn't like.

Any help appreciated. Cheers

Comment: Not perfectly clear what you want. Let's start with one stack. Does this stack represent the *colour channels* and if yes how many, RG, or RGB, or more channels? Please describe in great detail how the stack looks like. Last but not least it would help to get access to such a stack. I'm sure and in the end the solution is rather simple.

Comment: Hey @Herbie thanks for your response. Each stack consists of around 360 projections of a two separate CT scans. These stacks are combined into a single composite using Colour Merge. One CT stack is assigned the red channel, the other the green. The end result is a composite where each single image of the stack represents the same angle of the two separate CT scans. I want to measure the the profile of each single image of the composite, so total 720 profiles, one for each image containing a red and green channel profile. Stack link  [link](https://imgur.com/a/o8zTbgl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below please find an ImageJ **demo**-macro that generates a table showing in the first column the selection distances, in the next two columns the selection values in the red and green channel of the first slice of the stack and in the following columns the red/green selection values of the remaining slices. The table can finally be saved in csv-format by specifying the directory.

(The demo requires an **open** internet connection in order to load the demo stack.)

```
//imagej-macro "profilesOfComposite" (Herbie G., 13. March 2024)
requires("1.54i");
run("Confocal Series"); // load demo stack
makeLine(199,179,199,219); // demo selection
Stack.getDimensions(na,na,na,sl,na);
Stack.getUnits(xyU,na,na,na,vU);
p=getProfile();
d=Array.getSequence(p.length);
toScaled(d,newArray(0));
tbl="Profiles";
Table.create(tbl);
Table.setColumn("Distance ["+xyU+"]",d,tbl);
for (j=1;j<=sl;j++) {
   Stack.setSlice(j);
   Stack.setChannel(1);
   p=getProfile();
   Table.setColumn("Red #"+j,p,tbl);
   Stack.setChannel(2);
   p=getProfile();
   Table.setColumn("Green #"+j,p,tbl);
}
Table.save("");
exit();
//imagej-macro "profilesOfComposite" (Herbie G., 13. March 2024)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Herbie, you're a star. The only thing I had to adjust was the fact I was drawing an ROI each time so for each iteration of the loop I had to call "Stack.setSlice(j);
    waitForUser("Draw a polygon. Press Okay to continue...");
    getLine(x1, y1, x2, y2, line_width);" Thank you so much again!